# Client side crop with preview before upload

Tags: angularjs, file, upload, blueimp

I'm trying to implement client side crop with https://github.com/alexk111/ngImgCrop into https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload using Angular, such as this demo: https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/angularjs.html

What i'm trying to accomplish is to combine similar functionality of these two:

- https://blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Load-Image/
- https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/angularjs.html

I want to allow user to crop image before uploading it, but i'm having trouble to find any information of the image. `file`is empty inside the `ng-repeat`, because the image is not uploaded so where do i find the data of the image? Only thing i've managed to find is the `<canvas>` which is being appended in js/jquery.fileupload-angular.js:385 `$element.append(preview);`.

I should pass the data of the original image for the ng-crop module and it should then pass a thumbnail back to the `blueimp file uploader` so that user could see a thumbnail of the cropped file he/she is about to upload. I want to add on the `ng-repeat` a button, such as `<button type="button" class="btn btn-default crop" data-ng-click="file.$crop()" data-ng-hide="!file.$crop">Crop</button>` which should open up a modal where is the crop-module.

I'm not asking you to provide me a 100% full source code which i could just copy paste and everything should work fine, i'm hoping to get some advices on where should i start and/or how this could be done.

If you happen to know any better module for cropping the image, please feel free to let me know, its not necessary for me to use the `ngImgCrop`, as long as it works with `angular` and `blueimp file upload`.

Comment: You can access the cropped image using the variable you assign to `result-image`. E.g. `result-image="myImage"`, in the controller it is assigned to `$scope.myImage`.

Comment: I'm unable to get this to work.. Should this ```$scope.myImage``` be accessible in ```js/jquery.fileupload-angular.js:385``` or where? I need access to the original file and for the thumbnail so that i could pass the original file (or blob, whatever it is) for ```ngImgCrop``` and it should pass the thumbnail back to ```blueimp file uploader```

Comment: Did you use `handleFileSelect` function? You can access the original file using the `image="myImage"` and the cropped image using `result-image="croppedImage"`.

Comment: Ah, so you were talking about ```ngImgCrop```the whole time? Well my problem is more "how can i access the file to be uploaded in ```blueimp file upload```" rather than "how do i pass the image to ```ngImgCrop```".
I have no clue where does the ```blueimp file upload``` store the image i'm trying to upload, so that i could manipulate it as i please.

Comment: Well, in my experience I access/get the file using the `handleFileSelect` function even without the cropper.

Comment: But isn't the ```handleFileSelect``` a function in ```ngImgCrop```?
https://github.com/alexk111/ngImgCrop/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=handleFileSelect <- here it CAN be found

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=handleFileSelect <- here it CAN'T be found.

The problem ISN'T "How can i pass an image to ```ngImgCrop```", the problem is "How can i access the image of ```blueimp file upload```".

Forget the whole ```ngImgCrop``` from this equation, my problem stands only WITH ```blueimp file upload```.

Comment: ..and even if the ```handleFileSelect``` was the function i needed, i have no clue what parameters should i pass to it. Meaning; how do i access some one specific file of the queue from the blueimp file upload? I lack the knowledge on "in which variable does blueimp file upload store the files and how can i access to one of the files".